# Ajax not sending response when sending php variable LARAVEL

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

when sending ajax request to controller i am getting a the success aler message.

**View**

```
  $(".SendEvents").click(function(e){
 
       e.preventDefault();
 
       var ids = $(this).attr("id"); 
 
       $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url:"{{ route('ajaxRequest.post') }}",
          data:{id:ids},
          success:function(data){
             alert(data.success);
          }
       });
 
   });
```

**Controller**

```
   {
       $input = $request->all();

       return response()->json(['success'=>'Your Event Are Sent Successfully to Your Email']);
   }
```

But when adding a php variable to the data sent i a not getting the response alert as below

**View**

```
       e.preventDefault();

       var ids = $(this).attr("id"); 
       var sss= <?php echo "hello" ?>
       $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url:"{{ route('ajaxRequest.post') }}",
          data:{id:ids,sss:sss},
          success:function(data){
             alert(data.success);
          }
       });

   });
```

Comment: user var sss=' <?php echo "hello" ?>';

Answer (score 0):

Easily put this variable in single / double quotes

```
var sss= "<?php echo "hello" ?>";
```